# Копирование информации из TextView в буфер

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток.

Я хочу сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку содержимое `TextView` копировалось в буфер.

```
    Button copyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.copyButton);

    TextView generatedCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.generatedCode);
    String stringYouExtracted = generatedCode.getText().toString();
    int startIndex = generatedCode.getSelectionStart();
    int endIndex = generatedCode.getSelectionEnd();
    stringYouExtracted = (stringYouExtracted).substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(stringYouExtracted);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", stringYouExtracted);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
```

Данный код работает некорректно из-за строчки:

```
stringYouExtracted = (stringYouExtracted).substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

кидает `ClassCastException`.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а зачем вы берёте имя переменной в скобки?  (stringYouExtracted).substring(startIndex, endIndex);

Comment: Вообще непохоже, чтобы проблема была именно из-за приведённой строки. Выложите, пожалуйста, трассировку стека.

Comment: я использовал данный пример
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624763/android-copy-to-clipboard-selected-text-from-a-textview

Comment: В примере нет никаких скобок, почему вы решили, что вам они нужны? ClassCastExeption говорит о том, что у вас ошибка приведения типа, вы и пытаетесь привести к типу этими скобками, когда вам нужно просто взять подстроку из строки.

Comment: Это последствие склеивания нескольких примеров в один. Скобки убрал, но теперь приложение не запускается и в log кидает

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{company.generator/company.generator.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0

Comment: @Maksims, внесите изменения в пост, соответствующие изменениям в коде

Comment: я убрал скобки, но все равно ругается на строчку
stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

Comment: @Ksenia Проблема все ещё существует, можете объяснить по подробней о её решении.

Answer (score 1):

В каком методе находится этот ваш код? Скорее всего, в методе `onCreate`, который начинает выполняться при запуске приложения. Следовательно, в вашем `TextView` с `id`, равным `generatedCode`, не может быть выделенного текста, поэтому ваши `startIndex` и `endIndex` оба равны -1. Из-за этого вы и получаете ошибку. Перенесите код в другой метод (например, в метод обработки нажатия на кнопку) или проверяйте значение `startIndex` и `endIndex` на неравенство -1, например:

```
...
int startIndex = generatedCode.getSelectionStart();
int endIndex = generatedCode.getSelectionEnd();
if (startIndex != -1) {
    stringYouExtracted = stringYouExtracted.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
...
```

А лучше сделайте и то, и другое.